# Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake, pthreads

I am trying to create a c++ project with **Netbeans** from existing source, but I am stuck with an error during the pre-build process and I can’t figure out what leads to it. The first one is a CMakeError, which is shown below:

```
Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_394d9/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/e/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/src.c.obj

E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/src.c.obj -c E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c: In function 'main':
E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:15:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_atfork'; did you mean 'pthread_join'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   15 |   pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   pthread_join
Linking C executable cmTC_394d9.exe

"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a
C:/MinGW/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects1.rsp
E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/gcc.exe -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o cmTC_394d9.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_394d9.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/linklibs.rsp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_detach'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cancel'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_join'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/cmTC_394d9.dir/objects.a(src.c.obj):src.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTC_394d9.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/e/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTC_394d9/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

static void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

And the terminal output is:

```
cd 'E:\Yifan\Hiwi-FSD\FluCo1\Libraries\fsd-libs\trunk\build-dev'
C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -G Unix Makefiles -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/g++.exe -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g3 -gdwarf-2 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g3 -gdwarf-2 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DPROJECT_SUFFIX=-dev ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The cmake will use build type Debug
-- libfsd-io-dev version  is 1.0+
-- Install include dir include/fsd-io-dev
-- fsd-io-dev PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/IO
-- fsd-io-dev Build directory = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/MinGW/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.26") 
-- Checking for one of the modules 'openssl'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:843 (message):
  None of the required 'openssl' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  IO/CMakeLists.txt:47 (pkg_search_module)


-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- libfsd-log-dev version  is 1.0+
-- fsd-log-dev PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/Log
-- fsd-log-dev Build directory = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev
-- Install include dir include/fsd-log-dev
-- libfsd-math-dev version  is 1.0+
-- fsd-math-dev PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/Math
-- fsd-math-dev Build directory = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Libraries/fsd-libs/trunk/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

PRE-BUILD FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 8s)
```

Can anyone please help me about it? If you need any further information, I would be glad to offer. I have totally no idea about what’s the cause and where may I find it. I would really appreciate your help, thanksss!!

Comment: The code above is unrelated to your program. The related line to your program is "CMake Error" with the very clear reason "None of the required 'openssl' found".

Comment: @S.M. Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I also thought that presviously, but I have already installed `OpenSSL` and also added the path as an environment variable. I installed openssl here: `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`. And I added the path `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` as environment variable. Do I miss anything? Appreciate your further help!